# Splitting a large string into chunks for adding records to a table progressively

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I need to find the best way to go, 
from a cost-time-performance point of view, 
for splitting a large string (just one line) 
into chunks.

The main goal is adding records to a table progressively using `.append( content, [ content ] )` and `.delay( duration, [ queueName ] )` without blocking page.

The string looks like this

`<thead><th> .. </th><thead><tbody><tr> .. </tr><tr> .. </tr><tr> .. </tr> .................. <tr> .. </tr></tbody>`

Any ideas?

Comment: 1) How large is the string? 
2) Do you have control over where the string is coming from?
3) Have you tried dropping it all on the page and have you confirmed that it slows the page down?

Comment: 1) The string is about 2MB, 2) getting this string requires about 2 seconds, 3) using `.html( htmlString )`, it requires about 20 seconds with google chorome and more with other browser.

Comment: Can you better define "blocking page"?  Are you talking rendering time, browser/process complaining about "not responding"?

Comment: For blocking page I mean when `.html()` is used to set the content, the page is not usable.

Comment: How many tables rows are you appending .. at a time?  and total rows?

Comment: Have an example you can link to?  Put something up on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

If you can make changes on the webserver serving the long string of data, you could use [chunked data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). Basically, you send a "chunk" of data (in your case, could be a single row or a set of rows in the table) that you can then `.html(...)` into the table.

Create the table using the `table` tag and then request for data. As the data comes in as rows (including `thead` first, and then `tr`), append these rows to the table.

Depending on the webserver you're using, the actual code for chunked transfer will differ. Check out the link to know about how it works. Usually, most webserver technologies have some way to do a chunked transfer as part of HTTP 1.1

---

in nodejs, for example, keeping a connection alive (`Connection: keep-alive`) and then sending data of different lengths `Content-Length:10`, `response.write('Something\r\n')`; `Content-Length:15`, `response.write('Something else\r\n')` and repeat) should work

Comment: This web service is using multi-tier architecture. 1) the bottom layer is using cherryPy (python) 2) the front-end layer is using Apache (PHP). May you point out some example for implementing chunked transfer data using this context (Apache end/or CherryPy)?

Comment: Maybe the simplest way to accomplice my task is just to use `myString.slice(0,x)` in my javascript code and then iterate.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about CherryPy! But it's been quite a few days and I'm sure you've searched for Apache's chunked transfer capabilities already. Slicing the string in JavaScript would still require the whole string! That way, there would be no performance boost from the server/connection. On the JS side, I would recommend using [DocumentFragment](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/) to actually render data in HTMLElements.